# Mapping JSON key-value pairs from source to destination using Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Using Python `requests` I want to grab a piece of JSON from one source and post it to a destination. The structure of the JSON received and the one required by the destination, however, differs a bit so my question is, how do I best map the items from the source structure onto the destination structure?

To illustrate, imagine we get a list of all purchases made by John and Mary. And now we want to post the individual items purchased linking these to the individuals who purchased them (**NOTE**: The actual use case involves thousands of entries so I am looking for an approach that would scale accordingly):

Source JSON:

```
{
    'Total Results': 2, 
    'Results': [
        {
            'Name': 'John',
            'Age': 25,
            'Purchases': [
                {
                    'Fruits': {
                        'Type': 'Apple',
                        'Quantity': 3,
                        'Color': 'Red'}
                        }, 
                {
                'Veggie': {
                    'Type': 'Salad', 
                    'Quantity': 2, 
                    'Color': 'Green'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Mary',
            'Age': 20, 
            'Purchases': [
                {
                    'Fruits': {
                        'Type': 'Orange',
                        'Quantity': 2,
                        'Color': 'Orange'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Destination JSON:

```
{
    [
        {
            'Purchase': 'Apple', 
            'Purchased by': 'John',
            'Quantity': 3, 
            'Type': 'Red',
        }, 
        {
            'Purchase': 'Salad', 
            'Purchased by': 'John', 
            'Quantity': 2, 
            'Type': 'Green',
        },
        {
            'Purchase': 'Orange', 
            'Purchased by': 'Mary',
            'Quantity': 2, 
            'Type': 'Orange',
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Could you add your current implementation code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just consider loop through the dict.

```py
res = []

for result in d['Results']:
    value = {}
    for purchase in result['Purchases']:
        item = list(purchase.values())[0]
        value['Purchase'] = item['Type']
        value['Purchased by'] = result['Name']
        value['Quantity'] = item['Quantity']
        value['Type'] = item['Color']
        res.append(value)
```

```
pprint(res)

[{'Purchase': 'Apple', 'Purchased by': 'John', 'Quantity': 3, 'Type': 'Red'},
 {'Purchase': 'Salad', 'Purchased by': 'John', 'Quantity': 2, 'Type': 'Green'},
 {'Purchase': 'Orange', 'Purchased by': 'Mary', 'Quantity': 2, 'Type': 'Orange'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically what you're suggesting is looping through the dict on each result and then, in there, grabbing the items purchased while assigning new keys to the values, and put all of that in a new dict which is then put into a new list, right? For the inner-most loop, I am not fully understanding `item = list(purchase.values())[0]`Could you please elaborate on that (including the index)? Thanks

Comment: @Zaphod `dict.values()` gets all the values of dictionary `dict`. index `0` means to get the first value.